# Can we keep the lazers after the ME 3 promo? Please?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, me3missions

How about if I say Please 40 times?, What about then?

Please please please please *please please please please please* please please please please please please please please please please **please please please please** please please please please please please please please please please please please ***please please please please please!***

Also, I want to take this opportunity to thank Jin for our AMAZING AWESOME LAZERS.

Also, can we have them on Meta too? GREYSCALE LASERS. Imagine the possibilities!

Comment: @badp I alternated between multiple variant spellings for a reason! This isn't the time to take sides!

Comment: but now we have two different tags with one question each! BOTH tags are _dooooooooooooooooooomed_ now to death!

Comment: LMFAO @ 'jin-fanclub'

Comment: I still want grayscale lasers!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The mothership lazers will stay after the promo ends.

Comment: META LAZERS? *Pweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeese?*

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz By the power of Greyscale!

Comment: Why not the smaller lasers, too?

Comment: Jin, can I be in your fanclub?

Comment: @Ender you know what to do, mail me bacon.

Comment: LoL, sure no problem, just keep in mind but the time it gets to you from where I'm at, it might be alive and more ready to eat you than you are to eat it.

Answer (score 16):

> mothership lazers stay.

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3711681#3711681

Comment: Yay Lazers! 4 more to go...