# Overwhelmed about Mass Effect 3 promo missions

Tags: discussion, contests, me3missions

Since [Mass Effect missions](http://me3missions.com) started, gaming portal has become a bit of a monotony of questions of questions tagged `mass-effect-3`. I think it's really cool for this site to attract games this way, even more if people is attracted in here, it's fantastic! Make gaming.stackexchange grow!!

I really wish this'll happen more with future games ([redesign is so cool!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4139/can-we-keep-the-lazers-after-the-me-3-promo-please). And hey, congrats [Raven Dreamer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/336/raven-dreamer) Fleet Admiral [recently accomplished](http://me3missions.com/#mission-6) mission!).

But I just feel a little overwhelmed, as my home page is looking always like this:

[image: interesting faded list]

I wish I had time to buy and play Mass Effect 3, in fact **I wish I had time to play any game**, so I just log into gaming, stackverflow, or whatever in my tiny spare time, but in here I just find this bunch of `mass-effect-3` tagged questions filling my 'interesting' and 'newest' list (specifically 41 out of the 50 first questions).

Adding the tag to my *ignored tags* makes nonsense because the questions won't hide, just fade out, and the 41 faded questions remain there.

Is there any other way I this can be dealt/solved?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the only other thing we can offer you is this:

If click your name to go to your user page, you can click "prefs" and on that page is a checkbox that will hide all the questions that have ignored tags.

Sadly, this won't load more questions to fill the gaps left by the hidden and ignored tags.  You'll see a relatively sparse list of questions instead.

Comment: Sadly, my 50 questions per page turns into 8 :\... well, it's something!

Comment: @Nacho If you reload the page, you should get a full page of 50 non-ignored results (at least on the home page).  If not, there's a bug.

Comment: @DavidFullerton http://postimage.org/image/brsk02r8d ... then there is a bug?

Comment: @DavidFullerton Now it seems to work.. could it be maybe a cache thing? I did reload the page many different ways...

Comment: @Nacho It works on the home page, but not the Questions page.  Your screenshot is from the latter.

Comment: @DavidFullerton thanks, hope it gets fixed soon

Comment: Pro-tip: The '[Unhide the Ignored Tags Hider](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/102057)' Greasemonkey script shows the 'hide ignored tags' checkbox in the sidebar, allowing one to easily toggle it anytime.