# How to deal with the large numbers of Diablo questions?

Tags: support, tags, diablo-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overwhelmed about Mass Effect 3 promo missions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4161/overwhelmed-about-mass-effect-3-promo-missions)

What is the best way to hide all the Diablo questions? Gaming has become almost unusable for me.

I already added diablo-3 to my ignored tags, but that just changes the colour and does not hide the questions, so there is almost no interesting content reachable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can hide ignored tags if you want:

1. go to your [profile page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/26344/wassersturm).
2. click on [prefs](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/26344).
3. check "hide ignored tags".

Comment: Note this makes some pages like the Questions page show almost no content sometimes, but the front page ("Top Questions") will work as normal minus the ignored questions

Comment: Pro-tip: The '[Unhide the Ignored Tags Hider](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/102057)' Greasemonkey script shows the 'hide ignored tags' checkbox in the sidebar, allowing one to easily toggle it anytime.

Answer (score 3):

[This StackApp](https://stackapps.com/questions/2372/unhide-the-ignored-tags-hider) adds the "Hide Ignored Tags" button to the front page, which will allow you to more easily toggle between hiding and showing your ignored tags.

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed a ton of questions just because people don't know about Elective mode or advanced tooltips - so tempted to make & answer one about 'What should beginners know about the Diablo 3 interface?' ... but I'm sure the SE police will deem it too generic and bury it through downvotes.

Comment: We already have several questions about both of those topics. This is what the flag/close as duplicate system exists for. Why exactly are you interested in adding *another* duplicate?

Comment: I'm **not** going to add another dup; just pointing out that several questions are just different approaches to the same answer - 'how do I have teleport & diamond skin?', 'can I change the spell on my mouse buttons to attack' and various permutations which aren't _exact_ dups

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/71821/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-skills-so-that-right-mouse-is-not-always-secondary Yet another ques. on elective mode :p