# How do I remove or avoid getting the ultralisk-huge StarCraft 2 'AnswerSwarm' promo banner in my profile page?

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, design, answer-swarm

I don't play StarCraft 2 and have no interest in seeing the 'AnswerSwarm' achievement points. I would prefer to see my profile details immediately when I view my profile page, but the 'AnswerSwarm' banner prevents this, as it is ultralisk-huge.

Users not logged in can also see the banner in my profile. I tested this by viewing [my profile page](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/4797/galacticninja) in private/incognito mode.

(I'm putting an answer on [how to remove the promo banner client-side with a browser extension](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7002/4797), but I am also making a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to allow disabling or opting-out of this server-side.)

---

I'm getting comments stating that this may be caused by posting in [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) or up/downvoting a [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) post since the start of the contest. However, [I have not posted in [starcraft-2]](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:4797%20%5Bstarcraft-2%5D). And I have downvoted one [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) question *after* I posted this meta post and seeing the banner. And my 'AnswerSwarm' achievements currently state "1 up/down votes cast". (I don't recall any other up/downvotes aside from that.) So that means that the banner was already being shown to me even *before* I cast an up/downvote on a [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) post since the start of the contest. I'm adding the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) tag, in case this is a bug.

---

Related questions if you would like to know how to hide specific tags, like [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2), in the questions feed:

- [How to deal with the large numbers of Diablo questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4743/4797)
- [Overwhelmed about Mass Effect 3 promo missions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4161/4797)

Comment: I'm not sure what determines this, but I don't see any AnswerSwarm banner on my profile

Comment: @MadScientist This is what I see: http://i.imgur.com/5ufQSB5.png

Comment: @badp I have downvoted one [starcraft-2] question *after* I posted this meta post and seeing the banner. And my 'AnswerSwarm' achievements currently state "1 up/down votes cast". (I don't recall any other up/downvotes aside from that.) So that means the banner was already being shown to me even *before* I cast an up/downvote on a [starcraft-2] post since the start of the contest. Possible bug?

Comment: Looking into this. I'll check in on whether there's an opt-out system. As for why the banner showed up before you even participated... that is also something to investigate.

Comment: Regarding the banner appearance before you posted this meta question - you have an up/downvote on a post from before then. The newer up/downvote, the one you made after this post, is on an ineligible post (ineligible would be things that are closed and/or deleted, or posted before the contest start - I recall reading this in our development of the ruleset but I notice that this information is absent from our contest page), and thus isn't counted.

Comment: @GraceNote I see. I regularly review posts in the review queue and may have up/downvoted more than one of the [starcraft-2] questions. Thanks for looking into it. I'll appreciate an opt-out option.

Comment: [status-completed] As the AnswerSwarm competition has completed (and the AdBlock Plus workaround seemed effective anyway).

Answer (score 5):

If you have the [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/) browser extension or a similar browser extension that allows Adblock Plus-syntax filters, adding this filter should remove it and collapse the screen space it occupies:

`gaming.stackexchange.com##.promo-container`

Comment: Preventing the answerswarm scripting from executing will also do it.

Comment: @fbueckert Can that be blocked through Adblock Plus? Know what filter should be added?

Comment: That's a noscript thing; the .js files are on answerswarm.com.